# NHibernate: How to properly refresh an Entity including child collections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, nhibernate

I am having trouble refreshing an Entity. In our application the basic workflow is

```
Master View (Entity List without Details)
-> Detail View (Editable View of a single Entity (performed in a new ISession))
-> Save/Discard Changes in Detail View
-> Return to Master 
-> Refresh the possibly changed Entity in the Master View ISession
```

I read multiple SO questions and blog posts about the various ways to refresh an entity but none of them seem to work as expected.

1. `ISession.Refresh(..)`

   This works for basic changes to the entity (one-to-one relation) but fails
   if a child collection of the entity was cleared (because NH tries to update
   now deleted Entities of the child collection.
2. `ISession.Evict(..); ISession.Get(..);`

   This was suggested in multiple answers as the solution to the many-to-one
   problem and indeed I can see the changed properties while stepping through
   the code in debug and also in the database. Unfortunately the 
   `ITransaction.Commit()` at the end of the read-only transaction inside the 
   Master View now fails with `NonUniqueObjectException`.
3. `ISession.Evict(..); ISession.Flush(); ISession.Get(..);`

   I tried this hoping the `NonUniqueObjectException` was only caused by the 
   `Evict(..)` not being flushed. Surprinsingly this does not cause the Exception 
   but instead writed the old state of the Entity back to the database which in 
   turn results in the last `Get(..)` to return the old state again effectively 
   overriding the previous changes.

   Further investigation (including searching the NH debug log) shows that the 
   call to `Evict(..)` indeed removes the Entity from the 1st level cache as 
   expected but also marks the old entity state as updated. The ISession is 
   also marked as dirty and writes the changes to the db on the following 
   `Flush()`.

I am really lost right now as I thought `Evict(..)` would ignore the old state and just remove the entity from the cache effectively forcing the next query to hit the database. I also verified that the `ISession` is marked as not dirty  before the call to `Evict(..)` and dirty afterwards. This seems wrong to me as I explicitly want to evict the entity to discard the old state.

At this point any advice would be appreciated. Is there a better way to refresh a complete object graph or do I have to call the methods in another order?

Cheers,
MrFloya

EDIT: I guess I should have clarified that I am talking about a WinForms application. I used the Term View above which are just regular Forms with a Controller behind it (Semi-MVC?).

Comment: To avoid any issues related to this - split your operations to WRITE and READ. E.g. use one web request for write, another for read.

Comment: Then, you just have to mimic the same. Create unit of work, operation (like web request) with ONE session. Flush it. close it. Create new unit of work, to load the data...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?